# Most used Linux terminal tools that take passwords as a parameter

Tags: authentication, passwords

I am writing a tools that basically searches scripts and configurations files for hard-coded passwords. My first approach is to identify the most commonly used Linux terminal applications that can be passed a password (and hence which provide authentication).

Do you know of a comprehensive list of such tools? I couldn't find any. However, my first thoughts included the following tools:

- wget
- curl
- nc
- ssh
- scp
- ftp
- telnet
- git
- mysql
- sftp

Am I missing important ones?

Comment: Although you want this for a post-exploitation script, the question itself is not a security question. What you want to do is to search all man pages for password parameters. That can be done by: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226686/how-to-grep-man-pages-for-a-word

Comment: A lot of people abuse the OpenSSL command line utility for file encryption and give it the password as a command line argument, which you could certainly add to your list.

Comment: I would think `sudo` could also earn a spot on this list

Comment: `unzip` might also find its way on your list as the `-P` flag has potential security implications explained [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)

Comment: @waymobetta I think `sudo` intentionally does not take passwords on the command line for that very reason. Though GnuPG and various file archivers like 7z may.